# Nginx bypassing proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

In my conf file I have

```
upstream backend {
        server xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
        server xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
        }
```

and then

```
location /adcode/adcode {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

But sometimes instead of request going to the upstream servers. It goes to http://backend/adcode/adcode.

```
016/01/10 14:14:46 [error] 18474#0: *149951 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 208.107.89.45, server: _, request: "GET /adcode/adcode?crid=1744&refUrl=&cbrs=51487486&zz=51 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://backend/adcode/adcode?crid=1744&refUrl=&cbrs=51487486&zz=51", host: "show.*****.com", referrer: "http://show.****.com/adcode/adcode?crid=1744&cbrs=50633123&zz=11"
```

I have no idea why its doing this. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is running on xx.xx.xx.xx:8080? Is it another webserver on remote machine? Probably the reason is the upstream timeout.

Comment: Another remote machine running tomcat.

Comment: In the error log I am seeing a lot of no route to host and no live up streams error

Comment: But why is it contacting http://backend/adcode/adcode..... It should be contacting one of the upstream servers...

Comment: Not sure, but I believe this is the way Nginx logs information - instead of logging IP address it logs upstream name. Can you connect Tomcat server directly, typing xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 in your browser?

Comment: If that was the case then why am I seeing the correct upstream server ip with the rest of the logs. Yes tomcat server is reachable it's working fine :(

Comment: Can you show the rest of the logs?

Comment: The upstream servers have no firewall (even stopped the ip tables service). Still getting no route to host and no live upstream error... The latter error containg the url instead of ip :(

Comment: I am only getting the error mentioned above and this one 2016/01/10 18:18:39 [error] 3003#0: *463593 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: _, request: "GET /adcode/adcode?crid=1731&refUrl=&cbrs=63282484&zz=51 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http:// xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/adcode/adcode?crid=1731&refUrl=&cbrs=63282484&zz=51", host: "show.xx.com", referrer: "http://www.xx.com/?campaign=facebook&utm_source=555&utm_campaign=555"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100280/discussion-between-curious-and-cykopath).